# Растянуть изображение по контейнеру

Tags: html, css, svg

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" style='height:100%'>
  <rect fill="rgb(93,59,174, 60%)" id="rect" x="18%" y="18%" width="64%" height="64%" rx="15"/></rect>
  <clipPath id="clip"><use xlink:href="#rect"/></clipPath> 
  <image xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/DRKXhrt/1.webp" height="100%" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```

Так понимаю изображение в блоке image, принимает высоту блока svg.
Как выполнить так, чтобы ширину и высоту примула width="64%" height="64%", то есть окружности... Блока, а затем как бы принимала радиус.

Comment: Изображение получается как под лупой, вернее центральный фрагмент

Comment: Ради интереса, с какой целью это делается на SVG?

Comment: В блоке еще элементы с текстом, необходимо чтобы все элементы они масштабировались под высоту родителя.

Comment: В теории ничего не мешает реализовать на HTML\CSS

Comment: Был бы пример, я с текстом что только не перепробовал, все криво на криво. Либо шрифт большой, либо наоборот...

Comment: Возможно решить задачу с SVG? Или это только с css/html возможно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вы хотите сделать размер картинки, такой же как и круга (`rect`), если так, то всё что вам нужно, это передать такие же атрибуты как у `rect` для `image`.

Демо

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="200">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/DRKXhrt/1.webp"  x="18%" y="18%" width="64%" height="64%"/>
  <rect fill="rgb(93,59,174, 60%)" id="rect" x="18%" y="18%" width="64%" height="64%" rx="15" stroke-width=".05" stroke="red"/>
</svg>
```

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="200">
  <rect fill="rgb(93,59,174, 60%)" id="rect" x="18%" y="18%" width="64%" height="64%" rx="15"/>
  <clipPath id="clip"><use xlink:href="#rect"/></clipPath> 
  <image xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/DRKXhrt/1.webp"  x="18%" y="18%" width="64%" height="64%" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```